# Replace function combined with if statements

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where chunks of text are wrapped the same, but their regex transformations are not the same.

Rather than near-duplicate replace calls, I was hoping to use a function callback within replace. However, it seems I can't use $1 and such? It just prints out '$1' literally, instead of the capture group.

```js
console.log(
    ('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}').replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, function(match){
     if ( '$1' === "text" ) {
      return '[$1/$2]';
     } else {
      return '[$1----$2]';
     }
    })
);
```

Should produce:

```
'[text/1] blah blah blah blah blah blah [para----2]'
```

But currently produces:

```
'[$1/$2] blah blah blah blah blah blah [$1----$2]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [pass a function into replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), it will take the captured groups as positional arguments after the full match parameter. It will not attempt to interpret the string returned from the function.

You can solve your problem by taking those parameters in the function, and using them to build the strings that you want to return:

```
('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}').replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, function(match, p1, p2){
    if ( p1 === "text" ) {
        return '[' + p1 + '/' + p2 + ']';
    } else {
        return '[' + p1 + '----' + p2 + ']';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Captures are passed as function parameters. You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

```
('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}').replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, function(match, $1, $2){
    if ( $1 === "text" ) {
        return '[' + $1 + '/' + $2 + ']';
    } else {
        return '[' + $1 + '----' + $2 + ']';
    }
});
```

The function passes captures as parameters `function(match, $1, $2)`

Comment: `if ( '$1' === "text" )` would perhaps never evaluate to true

Answer (score 0):

```
('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}').replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, function(match,patt,index){

    if ( patt === "text" ) {
        return '['+patt+'/'+index+']';
    } else {
        return '['+patt+'----'+index+']';
    }
});
```

Replace method return index and match value in function parameter as i using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [parse the arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) or if you know the number, you can get them as fixed parameters:

```js
console.log(
  ('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}')
  .replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, 
    function(match, capture1, capture2) {
      if (capture1 === "text") {
        return '[' + capture1 + "/" + capture2 + ']';
      } else {
        return '[' + capture1 + '----' + capture2 + ']';
      }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` variables are available only if replacement parameter in `replace()` function is string. In case of function, the captured content is to be accessed via parameters in function. So number of submatches provides the number of parameters in the function.

```js
console.log(
    ('{{text1}} blah blah blah blah blah blah {{para2}}').replace(/\{\{(\w+)(\d+)\}\}/g, function(match,p1,p2){
     if ( p1 === "text" ) {
      return '['+p1+'/'+p2+']';
     } else {
      return '['+p1+'----'+p2+']';
     }
    })
);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace